# How do I get data from Tapestry BeanEditForms?

Tags: java, forms, spring, tapestry, jdbctemplate

I'm using Tapestry 5 and I have a page on which I have a bean edit form. How do I get data submitted in that form after click on submit?  I don't want to use Hibernate to persist the data (I'm using Spring `JdbcTemplate`). I want to use the data from forms to add them to SQL query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `BeanEditForm`, you already have some kind of backing bean which you specified as the `object` parameter. That's where the data for the form is coming from when the form is rendered, and that's also where it is going when the form is submitted.

The `BeanEditForm` component contains a `Form` component just like when you'd hand-code your form. You can create [event handlers](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-events.html) for all the standard events in your page class, just like you usually would:

```
 @OnEvent(EventConstants.SUCCESS)
 void processMyForm() {
     //your code here
 }
```

Also check out the [Bean Edit Form Guide](http://tapestry.apache.org/beaneditform-guide.html) and the [component reference for the BeanEditForm component](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/BeanEditForm.html) on the Tapestry site.